# How to use Yarn as a Spark Resource Manager without Hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I am using Spark in Standalone mode due to which I am not able to run multiple spark jobs in parallel. I want to use Yarn as a Resource Manager but don't want to install Hadoop.

Is this possible ? if yes then please provide me steps otherwise could you please provide another possible solution.

I know, I can use Apache Mesos or Kubernetes instead of Yarn but I think installing Yarn is easy instead of other RM.

Comment: Are you considering using hdp sandbox?

Comment: no all I am using without any cluster manager.